# dconf - Custom icons are not displayed in the panel menu

Tags: 20.04, unity, icons, lightdm, cinnamon

The custom icon `custom-symbolic.svg` is not displayed in the panel menu.
This is a segment of a dconf file:

```
[org/cinnamon]
app-menu-icon-name='custom-symbolic'
```

The full path to the file I created is:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/custom-symbolic.svg
```

and has a resolution of 51x51 pixels.

The owner and permissions of that icon are identical to those of all other icons in that path.

If instead of `custom-symbolic` I insert `cinnamon-symbolic`, which is present at the same path, the panel menu icon is displayed correctly, as well as all the other icons already present in the path:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved:

```
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
```